# Problems with jest and Vuetify regarding aria-owns id in snapshot

Tags: jestjs, vuetify.js

Im having problem with jest-test with vuetify. If Im running a testcase by it own I get one value for aria-owns. Example:

```
<div role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="list-8" class="v-input__slot">
```

Im using webstorm so I just update the snapshot directly. BUT when Im running all testcases with npm run test. The testcase received this HTML instead:

```
<div role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="list-27" class="v-input__slot">
```

As you see the id for the aria-owns has been changed. And I dont know how to fix this. I tried several clear and reset methods for jest, for example: jest.clearAllMocks() and jest.resetModules(), and so on but nothing works.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did,

I've added a setup-file for test. In this case Im using vitest, but I guess you can do it with jest aswell.

setup.ts ->

```
//setup.ts
import { expect } from 'vitest';
import vueSnapshotSerializer from '../vitest-serializer-vue';

expect.addSnapshotSerializer(vueSnapshotSerializer);
```

And my SnapshotSerializer-file:

```
// tests/vitest-serializer-vue.ts

import { Wrapper } from '@vue/test-utils';

const isHtmlString = (received: string) => received && true && received[0] === '<';
const isVueWrapper = (received: Wrapper<any>) => received && typeof received === 'object' && typeof received['isVueInstance'] === 'function';

const removeUniqueAttributes = (html: string) =>
    html
    .replace(/ aria-owns="[-\w]+"/g, '')
    .replace(/ id="input-[-\d]+"/g, '')
    .replace(/ data-v[-\w]+=""/g, '')
    .replace(/ for="input-[-\d]+"/g, '')
    .replace(/ v-text-field--is-booted/g, '')
    .replace(/ style="height: [-\w]+;"/g, '')
    .replace(/ data-booted="[-\w]+"/g, '');

export default {
    test(received: any) {
    return isHtmlString(received) || isVueWrapper(received);
},
print(received: any) {
    let html = (isVueWrapper(received) ? received.html() : received) || '';
    html = removeUniqueAttributes(html);

    return html;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify 2 uses `this._uid` which is internal to vue and can't be reset. It is incremented for each component instance which is why you get a different value if you run a different number of tests.

Vuetify 3 has a custom `getUid` function which also increments but can be imported and reset before each test:

```
import { getUid } from 'vuetify/lib/util'

beforeEach(() => {
  getUid.reset()
})
```